# Question about a holomorphic map on the punctured unit disc in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have a holomorphic, univalent map $\psi: \mathbb{D}^{*} \to \mathbb{D}^{*}$ where $\mathbb{D}^{*}$ is the punctured, open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$. So $\psi$ maps the punctured unit disc to itself. We can extend $\psi$ to 0 since it has a removable singularity there. Question: is it true that $\psi(0)$ must be 0? It sure seems like it from continuity, but I'm having trouble proving it. Any insights?

Comment: No. Look at $\psi(z)=\epsilon z +z_0$ where $0<|z_0|<1$ and $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small. This is an injective holomorphic map which maps the unit disk into the punctured unit disk.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a bunch!